# Collapse panel on button click - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

How do you make a panel collapse when pressing a normal bootstrap button? Here's my code:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="border-color: #464646;">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="border-color: #BBBBBB; height: 35px; padding-top: 3px;">
        <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Select Object</div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <!--Object Buttons-->
            <button *ngFor="let object of objects" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" style="margin-right: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="doThings();"</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `panel-body` will collapse when I click the `panel-heading`, but I would like to have the panel-body collapse when clicking one of the 'object' buttons.

Answer (score 6):

You can apply the same `data-target="#collapse1"` to the button as the href has.

**href**

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Select Object</a>
```

**Button**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
```

Also, your button isn't closed. missing `>` to close it.

```
<button *ngFor="let object of objects" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" style="margin-right: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="doThings();"
```

**Example:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Select Object</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
          Button with the same data-target
        </button> Panel Body
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Select Object</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2">
          Button with the same data-target
        </button> Panel Body
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```